# How do you update an environment variable using Ruby and Chef?

Tags: ruby, path, environment-variables, chef-infra

I know how to set the variables for both user and machine.
The problem arises when I try to add to the PATH. Currently my code will overwrite what is in the PATH.

```
execute 'set java_home2' do
command "setx -m PATH2 \"D:\\Home"
*only_if {"PATH2" == " "}*
end
```

This currently ensures that the PATH will only run if there is no PATH. When the only_if is removed the problem of overwriting arises.

EDIT:
I am now able to modify the system variable but cannot work out how to do the same with the user variables

```
env 'path addition' do
key_name "PATH"
value (ENV["PATH"] + ";D:\\Home\\Apps\\variable")
:modify
end
```

Comment: Do you want the environment variable to live only in the scope of the Ruby process (e.g. the Chef script) or do you want to update it so that it is preserved after the script exits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
   #Append notepad to user PATH variable
registry_key "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Environment" do
  $path_name = ""
  subkey_array = registry_get_values("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Environment", :x86_64)
  subkey_array.each{ |val|
    case val[:name].include?("PATH")
    when true
        $path_name = val[:data]
        print "\n The User PATH is: #{$path_name}"
        break
    when false
      print ':'
    end
  }
    values [{
      :name => "PATH",
      :type => :string,
      :data => "#{$path_name};D:\\Home\\Apps\\Notepad++\\Notepad++"
      }]
  action :create
  #add a guard to prevent duplicates
  not_if {
      $path_name.include?("D:\\Home\\Apps\\Notepad++\\Notepad++")
  }
end
```

This code when ran from the CMD line will print the current User PATH variables, then it will append D:/Home/Apps/Notepad++/Notepad++ IF it is not currently in the PATH. If it already exists then this will be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for specifics in chef, but in ruby, you can access environment variables with the `ENV` hash. So for `PATH`, you could do the following:

```
ENV["PATH"] = ENV["PATH"].split(":").push("/my/new/path").join(":")
```

That will update your PATH for the duration of the program's execution. Keep in mind that:

1. This will only update `PATH` for your ruby script, and only temporarily. Permanently changing your `PATH` is more complicated and dependent on OS.
2. This code assumes you're using linux. In windows, the `PATH` delimiter is `;` instead of `:`, so you should update the code accordingly.

Comment: Correct for general Ruby but probably not what people mean in Chef as this only affects the environment locally in the Chef process.

Comment: @coderanger good point, I'll keep that in mind with future Chef questions!

Answer (score 1):

From the question, it looks like you are trying to add PATH on windows server. In that case you can use `windows` cookbook resource called `windows_path` for such operation:

```
windows_path 'C:\Sysinternals' do
  action :add
end
```

https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/windows

https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/windows